# Laravel 5.4 vue components not showing - laravel passport

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-passport

So I'm installing passport and following the guide of Taylor's video on laracast and my vue components. and when I pasted these components

> 

it's not freaking showing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So these are the possible solutions may try.

1. you need to update your node
2. you need to update your  npm
3. make sure your app.js is compiling properly, this is the one that happened to me.

UPDATED ANSWER

```
mix.copy('node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', 'resources/assets/js');
mix.copy('node_modules/jquery-ui-bundle/jquery-ui.min.js', 'resources/assets/js');
mix.copy('node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js', 'resources/assets/js');

mix.copy('node_modules/jquery-ui-bundle/jquery-ui.min.css', 'resources/assets/css');


/*bootstrap*/
mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

/*js files*/
mix.js(
    ['resources/assets/js/jquery.min.js',
    'resources/assets/js/jquery-ui.min.js',
    'resources/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js']
    , 'public/js/app.js');

/*other css*/
mix.combine([
    'resources/assets/css/jquery-ui.min.css'
 ], 'public/css/combined.css');

/*vue components*/
mix.js(
    ['resources/assets/js/app.js'],
    'public/js/components.js'
);
```